# Google Cloud App Engine - clearing Cloud Storage buckets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an project deployed to App Engine. I deployed it a few times (made only minor changes - the size of the project locally is still the same) and the amount of data in Cloud Storage keeps increasing (I am now over 5GB). Is there a way to clear some data in Cloud Storage? Is any of it redundant or will my deployed project crash if I delete the buckets?

Comment: Have you deployed your project with a different version number? Look at the console: delete versions that you don't need.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I deleted the versions as you recommended. But there is still 5GB of data stored in Cloud Storage under eu.artifacts.<appName>.appspot.com. Should I delete the whole bucket and deploy the project again?

Comment: If you don't have any active users, that's the easiest solution.

Comment: What about your ```staging``` bucket? When you deploy, your files are deployed to the staging bucket. You should clear those first. You can also change when data is automatically deleted from the ```staging``` or ```artifacts``` buckets by updating the lifecycle. See this article from us explaining the lifecycle and how to manage the values (see the 'Background' section) - https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/

Comment: @NoCommandLine thanks for your suggestion. I cleared it and I actually also deleted the whole artifacts bucket (the app still works), but somehow, even if there isn't the bucket in Cloud Storage anymore it still says it uses 5GB.

Comment: What is your language/version? If it's Python 3, is it possible you're deploying your virtual env? Do you have a gcloudignore file in your app folder?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I think I'm not deploying the virtual env and I have the gcloudignore file in my app folder. This are the contents: .gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
/setup.cfg

Comment: What is your language & version?